# Creating transect with square polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to create with QGis 2.2 (german version) several square polygons (1km ²) that seamlessly connect to each other, so that a strip ( transect ) of 9km times 1km length results . ( I once attached a picture of how it should look ) - 
http://www.myimg.de/?img=TransektArcMap75b51.jpg

Although I have installed the plugin " Rectangles ovals digitizing ", but can not choose here the edge length . In addition, the following square is to connect seamlessly . In ArcMap the cursor shows me when digitizing contacts with neighboring polygons or their vertexes or lines on , so you could work " seamlessly " .
Furthermore, each of the squares , partially each quadrant , then an attribute (here, an air quality index) to be assigned , in accordance with which the square to be dyed.

Are different colors within a shape based on various values (how it works in ArcMap ) possible?
For information on tools , etc. ..... I use the German user interface.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector grid` is the tool you are looking after.

Make sure your project CRS is in UTM or another transverse mercator projection (not EPSG:3857 or EPSG:4326).

Shapefiles do not have any colour, but you can style a shapefile layer any way you want depending on attribute values.

If you need a rotated grid, create a custom CRS with omerc projection.